# I want to create a user in django but create_user() method doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a user using create_user method but it's not working and not showing any errors

in my `views.py` I have the following code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages

class Signup(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'myqpp/signup.html')
    def post(self, request):
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        pas = request.POST.get('password')
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, pas)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/signin/')

class Signin(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'myapp/signin.html')
    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        pas = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=pas)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            print('Success')
            return redirect('/', context={"user":user})
        else:
            print('Failed')
            messages.error(request, 'Bad Credentials')
            return redirect('/signin/')
```

I always get the message "Bad credentials" and when I review the Users table in django `admin/` page it shows that there is no new user added
When I click the submit button on the signup page, console log is like this

```
[21/Aug/2022 15:31:50] "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3907
Failed

[21/Aug/2022 15:32:07] "POST /signin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

[21/Aug/2022 15:32:07] "GET /signin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3304
```

I don't know what is the problem as it's not showing any errors

This is `myqpp/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MainView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('signup/', views.Signup.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('signin/', views.Signin.as_view(), name='signin'),
    path('signout/', views.Signout.as_view(), name='signout'),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have wrong path in `action` attribute in `<form>` tag.

```
[21/Aug/2022 15:31:50] "GET /signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3907
Failed
```

When you submit signup form, you have to call with POST the signup page, not the signin (this can be seen with the 'Failed' text in the console).

Comment: Wow, I spent have day because of this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must use creat to create the field, not creat_user! And you must specify the name of each argument. Like this:

```
user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email, password=pas)
```